# IE7 Line Height issue?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a link containing a span which should read something like "link   +", this displays correctly in all browsers except ie7:

```
<a style="display: inline; width:200px;" href="">
    Open a ticket
    <span style="float: right">+</span>
</a>
```

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/nGJ5b/ in ie7 to see what I mean. Has anybody knowledge of a fix for this?

Comment: I don't have IE7, but if I look at it in IE8 with IE7 browser mode turned on I still see it. Is it that it's visible in IE7 but not in the right place or something?

Comment: Yes the '+' should be on the same line as the text only it seems to appear the line below it

Comment: Ok, yeah, I see what you're talking about now. No idea how to fix it, unfortunately.

Comment: For some unknown reason, if i place the span before anyother element it works :/ http://jsfiddle.net/nGJ5b/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing the span before any other element seemed to do the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/nGJ5b/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can try and display every element as a block:

```
<a style="display: block; width:200px;" href="">
    <span style="float: left; display: block;">Open a ticket</span>
    <span style="float: right; display: block;">+</span>
</a>
```

Of course, this will not be acceptable if you need that link to be inline.