# Line-height alternative for Internet Explorer <= 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Morning,
Internet Explorer 7 don't support line-height, it is ignored. How can I solve this problem? Is exist an alternative tag for Internet Explorer <= 7?

Comment: This might help: http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/haslayout.html

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355959/ie7-line-height-issue

Comment: Line-height isn't always ignored in IE7. Please describe your usage more fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use padding instead. Let's say your font is **12px** and yow want to set a line height of **20px** so that gives you `padding: 3px 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Please check for IE7 and below version browser line-height

http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/lineheightbug.html